# $\int h(x)h'(x) dx$ without u-substitution/parts

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have to calculate the following antiderivative without using u-sub, even though it's very easy that way. Any suggestions?

$$\int h(x)h'(x) dx$$

Comment: Hmmm...But why?

Comment: what can you use

Comment: Just open your eyes. The primitive $\frac{1}{2} h^2$ will jump in.

Comment: @Paul, since this question is assigned from a section of my textbook that hasnt covered u-sub yet

Comment: It's highly unusual to have integration by parts before u substitution.  Does that work?

Comment: Can't do parts either, i forgot to add it in the question

Comment: I guess I have to use some sort of thereom to solve this

Comment: Do you know the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: Yes I konw that

Comment: But that doesnt relaly apply here since Im not calculating a definite integral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use “rules” for computing an antiderivative. Since the derivative of
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(h(x))^2
$$
is
$$
f'(x)=h(x)h'(x)
$$
by the chain rule, you're done: an antiderivative of $h(x)h'(x)$ (over an interval) has the form
$$
\frac{1}{2}(h(x))^2+c
$$
for some constant $c$.

Comment: Perhaps your right, maybe its just a direct concept type question. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can do integration by parts this gives,

$$I=\int h(x)h'(x) dx$$

$$=h(x)h(x)-\int h(x)h'(x) dx$$

$$=h^2(x)-I+C_1$$

So that,

$$I=\frac{1}{2}h^2(x)+C$$

Comment: Rats!  Beaten to the punch!  +1

Comment: I can't do parts either Dx, shoudlve mentioned it in the question

Comment: Then what can you do @KSplitX ?

Answer (score 2):

Use integrating by parts to find an expression of $\int h(x) h'(x) \text{d}x$.

Answer (score 2):

By parts, let $u=h(x)$, $dv=h'(x)dx$
Then
$$\int h(x)h'(x)dx=h^2(x)+C-\int h(x)h'(x)dx$$
$$I=h^2(x)+C-I$$
So
$$I=\frac{1}{2}h^2(x)+C$$

Answer (score 2):

$\int h(x)h'(x)dx$

Set $u=h(x)$ and $dv=h'(x)dx$ then 
$$
du=h'(x)dx
$$
and
$$
v=h(x)
$$
Then by the formula $uv-\int v du$ this is 
$$
h(x)^2-\int h(x)h'(x)dx
$$
Thus 
$$
\int h(x)h'(x)dx=h(x)^2-\int h(x)h'(x)dx
$$
So 
$$
2\int h(x)h'(x)dx=h(x)^2
$$
so 
$$
\int h(x)h'(x)dx=\frac{h(x)^2}{2}+C
$$

Comment: I can't do parts either Dx

Comment: what can you use